# What is the best way to oversample a dataframe preserving its statistical properties in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, resampling, oversampling

I have the following toy df:

```
FilterSystemO2Concentration (Percentage)    ProcessChamberHumidityAbsolute (g/m3)   ProcessChamberPressure (mbar)   
0                     0.156            1                                 29.5                                28.4                                                            29.6                                28.4   
2                     0.149          1.3                               29.567                                28.9   
3                     0.149            1                               29.567                                28.9   
4                     0.148          1.6                                 29.6                                29.4
```

This is just a sample. The original have over 1200 rows. What's the best way to oversample it preserving its statistical propierties?

I have googled it for some time and i hve only come across resampling algorithms for imbalalnced classes. but that's not what i want, i'm not interested in balancing thr data anyhow, i just would like to produce more samples in a way that more or less preserves the original data distributions and statistical properties.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using `scipy.stats.rv_histogram(np.histogram(data)).isf(np.random.random(size=n))` will create `n` new samples randomly chosen from the distribution (histogram) of the `data`. You can do this for each column: this will respect the distribution (although it will not contemplate cross-correlations). Does that work for you?

Comment: Hi @Mstaino thank you very much, i think it will work yes. if you can publish this as an answer indicating how to apply this function to each column and creating a new oversampled df, i will be glad to accept it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `scipy.stats.rv_histogram(np.histogram(data)).isf(np.random.random(size=n))` will create n new samples randomly chosen from the distribution (histogram) of the data. You can do this for each column:

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.random(100)*3, 'y': np.random.random(100) * 4 -2})
n = 5
new_values = pd.DataFrame({s: stats.rv_histogram(np.histogram(df[s])).isf(np.random.random(size=n)) for s in df.columns})
df = df.assign(data_type='original').append(new_values.assign(data_type='oversampled'))
df.tail(7)
>>          x         y    data_type
98  1.176073 -0.207858     original
99  0.734781 -0.223110     original
0   2.014739 -0.369475  oversampled
1   2.825933 -1.122614  oversampled
2   0.155204  1.421869  oversampled
3   1.072144 -1.834163  oversampled
4   1.251650  1.353681  oversampled
```

Comment: Thank you Mstaino!! That's exactly what i was looking for :)